# Masking array X based on a condition with array Y of different size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have two 1-dim arrays `X` and `Y` of different size. I am trying to build the 2-dim array resulting from a condition on `X` and `Y`. For instance:

```
X = np.array([0.3, 2.1, 4.3])
Y = np.array([1.5, 3.5])
mask = X > Y[:,np.newaxis]
```

and now I would like to perform something akin `X[mask] = X[mask] + 1`, so that for the example above it would result in:

```
newX = np.array([0.3, 3.1, 5.3],[0.3, 2.1, 5.3]])
```

I managed to get this result by doing:

```
newX = np.append(X, X).reshape(2,3)
newX[mask]=newX[mask]+1
```

But this hardcodes the length of the `Y` array (2 in the example), and includes a copy with `np.append` which is costly in cases where `X` and `Y` are actually large arrays (and it is probably quite ugly as well). Is there a correct way to do this?

Comment: ok, I just recalled np.outer right after pushing "enter", so at least this removes the hardcoding: `newX=np.outer(np.ones_like(Y),X)` but I am still not sure at all that this is the most efficient or correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case, where you wish to add 1 wherever `mask` is True,
perhaps the simplest way is to take advantage of broadcasting and dtype
promotion -- that is, booleans are treated as ints in numeric context.

```
In [49]: X + mask
Out[49]: 
array([[ 0.3,  3.1,  5.3],
       [ 0.3,  2.1,  5.3]])
```

Use broadcasting instead of an explicitly tiled copy of `X` if possible.
However, if you need `newX` you could use

```
In [54]: np.tile(X, (Y.size,1))
Out[54]: 
array([[ 0.3,  2.1,  4.3],
       [ 0.3,  2.1,  4.3]])
```

[`np.tile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) avoids the multiplications done by `np.outer` so it is faster for this purpose.

---

For example, with this setup:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit 
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

timing = collections.defaultdict(list)
Ns = np.linspace(10, 10000, 5).astype(int)
Ms = np.linspace(10, 10000, 5).astype(int)

for N, M in zip(Ns, Ms):
    X = np.random.random(N)
    Y = np.random.random(M)
    timing['tile'].append(timeit.timeit(
        'np.tile(X, (Y.size,1))',
        'from __main__ import np, X, Y',
        number=10))
    timing['outer'].append(timeit.timeit(
        'np.outer(np.ones_like(Y),X)',
        'from __main__ import np, X, Y',
        number=10))


plt.plot(Ns*Ms, timing['tile'], label='tile')
plt.plot(Ns*Ms, timing['outer'], label='outer')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

[image]

As the size of the arrays get larger, the difference between `tile` and `outer`
*should* diminish relative to total time because the time required to
allocate/manage large arrays in RAM/swap overwhelms the relatively small
computational costs.

Comment: Thanks! About the "adding 1", yours is a nice trick but indeed this was just for the example on stackoverflow, my real problem has a more complex computation when the condition is met. As for the np.tile, interestingly it is twice slower if I make the mistake to set the tiling value to 1 instead of 1. (overhead in type allocation I presume?), and marginally slower (20.5s against 19.7s in my test %timeit run) if not. So the gain of not performing the multiplication does not show up, at least not in this test run.... Syntactically np.tile is nicer though, so still an improvement!

Comment: If `np.tile` is taking 20+ seconds, I suspect you must be dealing with huge arrays. If the array does not fit fully in RAM then your OS will use swap space to accommodate the rest. Moving pieces of the array in and out of RAM is slow and that may explain why `np.tile` and `np.outer` are taking so long. The fix is either to acquire more RAM or devise a more clever algorithm which does not require so much memory, such as (perhaps) by doing the computation in blocks...

Comment: Btw, I do not understand what you meant by "...twice slower if I make the mistake to set the tiling value to 1 instead of 1" ?

Comment: hi, sorry it was a mistake on my side, I put the wrong type in the call.